get elapsed time to most recent condition by group. Bench
I would like to speed up this code in data.table. I think I can do better.
It is a typical looking backwards for the last TRUE predicate an then accounts the time to the current row. All this by group.
I am running this with a 300.000 rows and 200.000 groups, and need to calculate many columns (metrics) like that. Hence, the velocity is important to me.
I made a smaller data Example:
 data <- data.table(
      SYSKEY = c(
        12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 
        22, 21, 24, 25, 26
      ), 
      Customer = c(
        "John", "John", "John", "Tom", "Tom", 
        "Tom", "Sally", "Sally", "Sally", "Sally"
      ), 
      TRAN_DATTIM = as.Date(
        c(
        "28-02-2024", "28-02-2024", "02-03-2024", "02-03-2024", "02-03-2024", 
        "02-03-2024", "02-03-2024", "02-03-2024", "03-03-2024", "03-03-2024"
        ),
        format="%d-%m-%Y", origin="01-01-1900"
      ), 
      Product = c(
        "Eggs", "Milk", "Bread", "Butter","Eggs", 
        "Milk", "Bread", "Butter", "Eggs", "Wine"
      )
  )

My function and execution code:
library(data.table)    

build_recency <- function(
    data,
    name,
    predicate,
    aggregated_fun = "TIME",
    gamma = 0.0001,
    rolling_over
){
  
  UseMethod("build_recency")
  
}


build_recency.data.table <- function(
    data,
    name,
    predicate,
    aggregated_fun = "TIME",
    gamma = 0.01,
    rolling_over = "PAN"
){

  predicate <- enexpr(predicate)

  data[,
    PRED := fifelse(eval(predicate) == TRUE, 1L, 0L)
  ]
  
  setorderv(
    data,
    c(rolling_over, "TRAN_DATTIM", "SYSKEY")
  )
  
 # make a left-join, that trail last TRUE predicate PRED in their 
 # rolling over's group

data[,c(
 .SD[
   # last timestamp with PRED==TRUE
   PRED == 1, .(TRAN_DATTIM, SYSKEY)
 ][
      .SD,
      # assure that do not get itself
      on = .(TRAN_DATTIM <= TRAN_DATTIM, SYSKEY < SYSKEY),
      # in that cartesian product, get the latest.
      # DT must be ordered by TRAN_DATTIM!
      mult = "last",
      # j
      # return all .SD cols, plus new column x.TRAN_DATTIM 
      # I help me with env argument.
      # https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-programming.html#:~:text=Substituting%20lists%20of%20arbitrary%20length
      cols,
      env = list(
        cols = I(c(colnames(.SD), "x.TRAN_DATTIM"))
      )
    ]
  ),
   by = rolling_over
  ][,
    # building recency and cleaning auxiliar vars
    `:=` (
      name = {
        x <- as.numeric(
          difftime(
              TRAN_DATTIM,
            x.TRAN_DATTIM,
            units = "days"
          )
        )  

        if(aggregated_fun == "EXP")
          x <- exp(-gamma * x)
        
        x
      },
      x.TRAN_DATTIM = NULL,
      PRED = NULL
    ),
    env = list(
      gamma = I(gamma),
      name = name
    )
  ]

}

 data2 <- build_recency(
    data = data,
    name = "RECENCY",
    predicate = if_else(
      Product == 'Eggs', TRUE, FALSE
    ),
    gamma = 0.001,
    rolling_over = 'Customer'
  )
  
  data2[]

Expected result:
     Customer SYSKEY TRAN_DATTIM Product RECENCY
      <char>  <num>      <Date>  <char>   <num>
 1:     John     12  2024-02-28    Eggs      NA
 2:     John     13  2024-02-28    Milk       0
 3:     John     14  2024-03-02   Bread       3
 4:    Sally     21  2024-03-02   Bread      NA
 5:    Sally     24  2024-03-02  Butter      NA
 6:    Sally     25  2024-03-03    Eggs      NA
 7:    Sally     26  2024-03-03    Wine       0
 8:      Tom     15  2024-03-02  Butter      NA
 9:      Tom     20  2024-03-02    Eggs      NA
10:      Tom     22  2024-03-02    Milk       0


So you want to calculate the RECENCY column? What is the logic in words?

I wanna count the number of days since the predicate is TRUE. In my example: How many days have been lasted since I bought Eggs until the current day?  NAs appear because I did not buy Eggs before. zero means you bought Eggs the same day or autoreference

John hasn't bought bread before (line 3)... where does the value 3 come from?

@s_baldur, it does not matter whether you bought positioned in the current line (vg. line 3 in your example). You want to know how many time has passed since you buy Eggs in line 3 for Jonh (= 3 days)

A speedy data.table-only version would be
data[  , PREDICATE_Date := fifelse(Product=="Eggs",TRAN_DATTIM,NA) 
   ][ , PREDICATE_Date := nafill(PREDICATE_Date,"locf"), by=Customer
   ][ , RECENCY := TRAN_DATTIM-PREDICATE_Date
   ][ , RECENCY := fifelse(Product=="Eggs", NA, RECENCY)
   ]

short explanation:

store date of predicate in separate column PREDICATE_Date
fill the NA in PREDICATE_Date with the most recent date of that customer
calulate time difference
set time difference to NA in predicate rows.


but collapse and timeplyr are indeed insanely powerful as @NicChr already explained.
I think the most efficient way is to use collapse inside a data.table, i.e. just copy the approach of @NicChr into a data.table.
Let's do some benchmarking :)
I replicated your toy data set N=5e4 times to get a dataset with 150000 (unique) customers:
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(collapse)
library(timeplyr)

N <- 5e4 ## Number of replicates of each customer
Data1 <- data[rep(1:10,N)] ## replicate data
Data1[,Customer:=paste0(Customer,rep(1:N,each=10))] ## make customer names unique
Data2 <- copy(Data1)
Data3 <- copy(Data1)
bench::mark(
dplyr.collapse={
  out <- Data1 %>%
    # arrange(Customer) %>%
    mutate(id = fcumsum(Product == "Eggs", g = Customer)) %>%
    mutate(RECENCY = time_elapsed(TRAN_DATTIM, "days", rolling = FALSE,
                                  g = pick(Customer, id))) %>%
    mutate(RECENCY = if_else(id == 0, NA, RECENCY)) %>%
    mutate(RECENCY = if_else(frowid(pick(Customer, id)) == 1, NA, RECENCY))
},
datatable={
  Data2[ , PREDICATE_Date := fifelse(Product=="Eggs",TRAN_DATTIM,NA)
      ][ , PREDICATE_Date := nafill(PREDICATE_Date,"locf"), by=Customer
      ][ , RECENCY := TRAN_DATTIM-PREDICATE_Date
      ][ , RECENCY := fifelse(Product=="Eggs", NA, RECENCY)
      ]
},
datatable.collapse={
  Data3[, id:=fcumsum(Product=="Eggs",g=Customer)
      ][, RECENCY:=time_elapsed(TRAN_DATTIM, "days", rolling=FALSE,
                                g=GRP(list(Customer,id)) )
      ][, RECENCY:=fifelse(id==0L, NA, RECENCY)
      ][, RECENCY:=fifelse(frowid(GRP(list(Customer, id))) == 1L, NA, RECENCY)]
}, check=FALSE )



# A tibble: 3 × 13
  expression              min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory    
  <bch:expr>         <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>    
1 dplyr.collapse       49.81s   49.81s    0.0201   72.56MB     0        1     0     49.81s <NULL> <Rprofmem>
2 datatable             9.67s    9.67s    0.103     2.34GB     1.45     1    14      9.67s <NULL> <Rprofmem>
3 datatable.collapse 224.11ms 252.68ms    3.96     53.53MB     1.98     2     1   505.36ms <NULL> <Rprofmem>
# ℹ 2 more variables: time <list>, gc <list>

So, there are gigantic differences in speed.
The data.table&collapse&timeplyr combination should manage your use case in well under a second :)


EDIT:
The main bottleneck in the dplyr approach is the usage of pick(...). When we replace it with GRP(list(...)), we get speeds much more similar to that of the data.table version

This is great, I think the bottleneck is actually the GRP algorithm selected. For some reason using GRP(pick(x, y), sort = FALSE) is much slower in this particular case than GRP(pick(x, y), sort = TRUE) where sort is the default.
When sort is FALSE, collapse uses a hash algorithm which is typically faster than the radix sort based algorithm.

As I suspected this was indeed the issue. I've updated the benchmark with an alternate version including GRP(..., sort = TRUE) and the results are comparable with data.table

This also explains why you get faster results when using GRP(list(...)) over my initial usage of pick(...) because the former uses sort = T.

Not data.table but you can use a mix of packages to achieve this very fast.
Both collapse and timeplyr have time-based functions that are optimised for data with millions of groups.
library(tidyverse)
library(collapse)
library(timeplyr)

out <- data %>%
  arrange(Customer) %>%
  mutate(id = fcumsum(Product == "Eggs", g = Customer)) %>%
  mutate(RECENCY = time_elapsed(TRAN_DATTIM, "days", rolling = FALSE, 
                                g = pick(Customer, id))) %>%
  mutate(RECENCY = if_else(id == 0, NA, RECENCY))
out
#>    SYSKEY Customer TRAN_DATTIM Product id RECENCY
#> 1      12     John  2024-02-28    Eggs  1       0
#> 2      13     John  2024-02-28    Milk  1       0
#> 3      14     John  2024-03-02   Bread  1       3
#> 4      21    Sally  2024-03-02   Bread  0      NA
#> 5      24    Sally  2024-03-02  Butter  0      NA
#> 6      25    Sally  2024-03-03    Eggs  1       0
#> 7      26    Sally  2024-03-03    Wine  1       0
#> 8      15      Tom  2024-03-02  Butter  0      NA
#> 9      20      Tom  2024-03-02    Eggs  1       0
#> 10     22      Tom  2024-03-02    Milk  1       0

## To make first row NA

out %>%
  mutate(RECENCY = if_else(frowid(pick(Customer, id)) == 1, NA, RECENCY))
#>    SYSKEY Customer TRAN_DATTIM Product id RECENCY
#> 1      12     John  2024-02-28    Eggs  1      NA
#> 2      13     John  2024-02-28    Milk  1       0
#> 3      14     John  2024-03-02   Bread  1       3
#> 4      21    Sally  2024-03-02   Bread  0      NA
#> 5      24    Sally  2024-03-02  Butter  0      NA
#> 6      25    Sally  2024-03-03    Eggs  1      NA
#> 7      26    Sally  2024-03-03    Wine  1       0
#> 8      15      Tom  2024-03-02  Butter  0      NA
#> 9      20      Tom  2024-03-02    Eggs  1      NA
#> 10     22      Tom  2024-03-02    Milk  1       0

In response to @hi_everyone there seems to be an issue with GRP(..., sort = FALSE) in this particular example so we can achieve a much faster result using the default sort = T
> bench::mark(
+   dplyr.collapse={
+     out <- Data1 %>%
+       # arrange(Customer) %>%
+       mutate(id = fcumsum(Product == "Eggs", g = Customer)) %>%
+       mutate(RECENCY = time_elapsed(TRAN_DATTIM, "days", rolling = FALSE,
+                                     g = pick(Customer, id))) %>%
+       mutate(RECENCY = if_else(id == 0, NA, RECENCY)) %>%
+       mutate(RECENCY = if_else(frowid(pick(Customer, id)) == 1, NA, RECENCY))
+   },
+   dplyr.collapse2={
+     out <- Data1 %>%
+       # arrange(Customer) %>%
+       mutate(id = fcumsum(Product == "Eggs", g = Customer))
+     groups <- GRP(out, c("Customer", "id"), sort = TRUE)
+     out <- out %>%
+       mutate(RECENCY = time_elapsed(TRAN_DATTIM, "days", rolling = FALSE,
+                                     g = groups)) %>%
+       mutate(RECENCY = if_else(id == 0, NA, RECENCY)) %>%
+       mutate(RECENCY = if_else(frowid(groups) == 1, NA, RECENCY))
+   }, 
+   datatable={
+     Data2[ , PREDICATE_Date := fifelse(Product=="Eggs",TRAN_DATTIM,NA)
+     ][ , PREDICATE_Date := nafill(PREDICATE_Date,"locf"), by=Customer
+     ][ , RECENCY := TRAN_DATTIM-PREDICATE_Date
+     ][ , RECENCY := fifelse(Product=="Eggs", NA, RECENCY)
+     ]
+   },
+   datatable.collapse={
+     Data3[, id:=fcumsum(Product=="Eggs",g=Customer)
+     ][, RECENCY:=time_elapsed(TRAN_DATTIM, "days", rolling=FALSE,
+                               g=GRP(list(Customer,id)) )
+     ][, RECENCY:=fifelse(id==0L, NA, RECENCY)
+     ][, RECENCY:=fifelse(frowid(GRP(list(Customer, id))) == 1L, NA, RECENCY)]
+   }, check=FALSE )
# A tibble: 4 × 13
  expression      min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory    
  <bch:expr>  <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>    
1 dplyr.coll…   13.2s   13.2s    0.0758   72.56MB   0.0758     1     1      13.2s <NULL> <Rprofmem>
2 dplyr.coll… 73.11ms 89.33ms    8.07     78.28MB  12.9        5     8   619.82ms <NULL> <Rprofmem>
3 datatable     3.45s   3.45s    0.290     2.34GB  10.1        1    35      3.45s <NULL> <Rprofmem>
4 datatable.… 75.76ms    80ms    9.77     53.53MB   7.82       5     4   511.53ms <NULL> <Rprofmem>
# ℹ 2 more variables: time <list>, gc <list>
Warning message:
Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.  

